# Processing blocks drawing function while writing to the serial port

Tags: java, arduino, processing

In Processing I've wrote a simple program which gets all pixel of a image and sends it's values to the serial port. This is done inside the draw function and it iterates through the pixel array in each draw event.

So for a image of 200 x 200 there are 40000 pixels and the draw function is called 40000 times. But I don't see the result of any change I make during this processing. After 30 seconds the data is serialized and only then all changes becomes visible.

What do I need in order to draw and see immediately the result during the writing to serial? Could a asynchronous thread be a solution? I've also tried this, and calling the redraw method, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm still working on the problem. Seems that all ideas provided yet doesn't work. But as soon as I found the solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

For a 200x200 image you will loop through 40000 pixels, but you shouldn't need to call the draw() function this often. You can have a loop for each each pixel running once per draw() call, in case your pixels are actually changing, otherwise, you can cache the pixel values once in `setup()`

Regarding writing to serial, it shouldn't be too complicated.
Here's a proof of concept sketch illustrating one way of writing a Thread that writes to serial in parallel:

```
import processing.serial.*;

int w = 200;
int h = 200;
int np = w*h;//total number of pixels

PImage image;

SerialThread serial;

void setup(){
  image = createImage(w,h,ALPHA);
  //draw a test pattern
  for(int i = 0 ; i < np; i++) image.pixels[i] = color(tan(i) * 127);
  //setup serial 
  serial = new SerialThread(this,Serial.list()[0],115200);
}
void draw(){
  image(image,0,0);
}
void mousePressed(){
  println("writing pixel data to serial port");
  for(int i = 0 ; i < np; i++) serial.write((int)brightness(image.pixels[i]));
}
//implement runnable - can run as thread, alternatively extend Thread
class SerialThread implements Runnable{

  Serial serial;

  boolean running = false;//keep the tread running

  int data;//store a byte to send
  boolean hasData;//keep track if the most recent data was written

  SerialThread(PApplet parent,String port,int baudrate){
    try{
      //setup serial
      this.serial = new Serial(parent,port,baudrate);
      //setup thread
      running = true;
      new Thread(this).start();
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.err.println("error opening serial port! please check settings (port/baudrate) and the usb cable");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
  //handled
  public void run(){
    while(running){//endless loop to keep the thread running
      if(hasData){//if there is data to write
        if(serial != null) serial.write(data); //send it via serial, if the port is open
        hasData = false;//mark that the data was sent
      }
    }
  }

  public void write(int data){
    this.data = data;
    hasData = true;
  }

}
```